# Localization for user profile information Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement page localization to my webpage made in asp.net-mvc. I understand how to implement titles and other modular data.

The problem comes when i want to give user/admin of this page rights to change his personal information/bio on her webpage if needed. Do i save the bio in the database? With another column in the table which indicates for which language it is meant?

Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Yeah, why not, there is nothing wrong with your suggested solution. It's a valuable information to know in what language the user's bio is written in. Perhaps the only thing you should consider is, if it makes sense for a user to create more records in different languages. But that depends on your specific application.

Comment: If the purpose is to find other bios in the language of choice, then add the extra column.  If all bios are going to be in the same language, do nothing.  If you intend to provide translations, use another table to keep a list of all the translations you have for that user.